# How to obtain video metadata from a video stored on Dropbox?

Tags: ios, swift, metadata, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

I don't know what I can do to obtain the duration of a video stored on Dropbox, thanks to the `SwiftyDropbox` API.

It sounds like these informations should be in an instance of `Files.VideoMetadata` class

I tried to use the `getMetadata` methods but the results doesn't contains the video duration, which is what I expect to get.

This is my current code :

```c
Dropbox.authorizedClient!
       .files
       .getMetadata(path: file.pathLower!, includeMediaInfo: true)
       .response({ (result, err) in
if let metadata = result as? Files.FileMetadata {
    print(metadata.name)
    if metadata.mediaInfo != nil {
        switch metadata.mediaInfo! as Files.MediaInfo {
            case .Pending:
                print("Pending")
            case .Metadata(let mediaMetadata):
                print(mediaMetadata)
        }
    }
}
})
```

`mediaMetadata` contains `{}`, and I can't get the duration of the video, nor other properties.

It seems it's because my video uploaded on Dropbox is in the `.mov` format. Any solutions in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you're calling [`getMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes11getMetadataFT4pathSS16includeMediaInfoSb14includeDeletedSb31includeHasExplicitSharedMembersSb_GCS_10RpcRequestCCS_5Files18MetadataSerializerCS2_26GetMetadataErrorSerializer_) with `includeMediaInfo` set to `true`. (Also, this was only recently added, so make sure you're running the latest version of SwiftyDropbox.)

The resulting [`FileMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/Files/FileMetadata.html#/s:vCC13SwiftyDropbox5Files12FileMetadata9mediaInfoGSqOS0_9MediaInfo_) will hopefully have [`MediaInfo`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/Files/MediaInfo.html#/s:FOC13SwiftyDropbox5Files9MediaInfo8MetadataFMS1_FCS0_13MediaMetadataS1_) set to an instance of [`MediaMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/Files/MediaMetadata.html). (It could also be `Pending` though, so be careful of that.)

Once you are looking at the `MediaMetadata` though, note that its fields are all set as optional, meaning it's unfortunately not guaranteed that they will be available.

This is because while Dropbox does make a best effort to extract this metadata, it can't always do so. This can vary from file to file.

Comment: I did it, but I get nothing, and I don't have any errors.
I have edited my question with my current code.

Comment: It seems it's because my video uploaded on Dropbox is in the .mov format. Any solutions in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You were actually very close, here is how you get the duration for videos:

```
if metadata.mediaInfo != nil {
   switch metadata.mediaInfo! as Files.MediaInfo {
   case .pending:
       print("Pending")
   case .metadata(let mediaMetadata):
       switch mediaMetadata {
       case let videoMetadata as Files.VideoMetadata:
           print(videoMetadata)
           print(videoMetadata.duration)
       case let photoMetadata as Files.PhotoMetadata:
           print(photoMetadata)
       default: break
       }
   }
}
```

You can use this to determine weather a file is a video or photo as well